# I need a help on how to check if the user exists in mysql cannot be added again?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my register.php codes

```
<?php 
include("dbconnection.php");
include("header.php");
include("validation/header.php"); 
include("functions/patient.php");

if(isset($_POST["button"]))
{
//select max value from patient db

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(patid) FROM patient");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
$maxpatid = $row[0];
$maxpatid++;
  }



// Insert records to patient table
$sql="INSERT INTO patient(patid,patfname,patlname,emailid,contactno,password)
VALUES
('$maxpatid','$_POST[pfn]','$_POST[pln]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[contact]','$_POST[password]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
}

?>
<!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
<?php include("menu.php"); ?>
<!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
<!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
<div id="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
      <h1>Patient Registration</h1>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>

      <?php
      if(isset($_POST["button"]))
{
?>
 <table summary="Summary Here" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Patient Registered Successfully</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="light">
            <td><b>Your Patient ID is : <?php echo $maxpatid; ?></b></td>
          </tr>
                </tbody>
      </table>
      <form method="post" action="patientaccount.php" id="formID1" class="formular" >
        <input name="btnlogin" type="submit" id="submit" value="Click here to Login"  class="submit"/>

      <p>
&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;
      </p>
      </form>
<?php
}
else
{
?>
<form id="formID" class="formular" method="post">
  <div align="center"><strong><b> Registration Page</b></strong></div>
  <label for="textfield">  First Name</label>
     <input type="text" name="pfn" id="textfield" class="validate[required] text-input" />
     <label for="textfield2">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="pln" id="textfield2" class="validate[required] text-input" />

      <label for="textfield4">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password"  class="validate[required] text-input"/>
      <label for="textfield3">        </label>


      Confirm Password
      <input type="password" name="textfield5" id="textfield5" class="validate[required,equals[password]] text-input" />


      Email ID
      <input type="text" name="email" id="textfield6" class="validate[required,custom[email]] text-input" />


      Contact No
      <input type="text" name="contact" id="textfield7" class="validate[required] text-input" />
    <div align="center">
        <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Register"   class="submit"/>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="reset" name="button2" id="button2" value="Reset"  class="submit"/>
</div>
 <p>
&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;
      </p>
</form>
<form method="post" action="patientaccount.php" id="formID1" class="formular" >
       <p>
<b>Already Registered?</b>
      </p>
       <input name="btnlogin" type="submit" id="submit" value="Click here to Login"  class="submit"/>

      <p>
&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;
      </p>
      </form>
     <?php
}
?> 
      <p>&nbsp;</p>

      <div id="respond">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="column">
      <div class="holder">
        <h2>Registration Page</h2>
        <p>Please enter First Name, Last Name, Password, Email ID, Contact number to Register Clinicosight.</p>
</div>
</div>
    <br class="clear" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Please someone help me to solve this problem. When i input the same details of exists user, it still accept and duplicate the data in mysql. I need some validation code in here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, maybe because you're not checking if the user exists. All you do is getting the max id from the table, increment it and use it for the new user.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) and have race conditions with the ID function. You should **NOT** be generating your own ids. there's `auto_increment` in mysql for a reason.

Comment: How to do it @CharlotteDunois? Could help me?

Comment: You should start over using a non-deprecated api like PDO or mysqi, mysql auto-increments, prepared statements to avoid sql injection and salted & hashed passwords.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `SELECT MAX(patid) FROM patient` use `SELECT $patid FROM patient` if the rows returned is more than 0 the patient already exitst

Comment: You mean $maxpatid or just $patid?

Comment: Just patid max is not required then check to see if the rows returned is more than 0

Comment: Im already change $maxpatid to patid. What should i put under while statement?

Comment: Guys, im still dont get the solution. Help me, please.

Comment: short of coding it for you, im not sure I can help you. All you need do is check to see if your select returned any rows from the database if it does than the patient ID already exists.

Answer (score 0):

try to change,

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(patid) FROM patient");
```

to

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT patid FROM patient");
if(mysqli_num_rows($result))
{
while(...
}
```

Comment: What should i put under while statement @chandu

Answer (score 0):

This example is not safe with SQL injection, but posting this for understanding the logic.

Consider your email field in table is unique. (Make one column of your table unique)

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT patid FROM patient WHERE emailid = '$_POST[email]' "); 
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

if( $num ==0) {
//email not exists, do insert 
} else if ($num ==1)
{
//email exists, duplicate, so discard
}
```